# Property not initialized at super.init call

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, initialization, swift, ios8

I have the following `init` method in my view controller:

```
init(mainViewController: UIViewController, settingsViewController: UIViewController, gap: Int) {
        self.mainViewController = mainViewController
        self.settingsViewController = settingsViewController
        self.gap = gap

        self.setupScrollView() // I get error here

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil) //and here.
    }
```

The `self.setupScrollView` method for now just looks like this:

```
func setupScrollView() {
        self.scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectZero)
        self.scrollView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)
    }
```

The errors I get are:

`self used before super.init call` and `Property 'self.scrollView' not initialized at super.init call`

I've looked at similar post without any luck. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by declaring `scrollView` as optional and moving the setup method call below the `super.init` call. The declaration would look like this:

```
var scrollView : UIScrollView?
```

And the initialisation:

```
init(mainViewController: UIViewController, settingsViewController: UIViewController, gap: Int) {
    //other stuff
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.setupScrollView()
}

func setupScrollView() {
    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectZero)
    scrollView!.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    view.addSubview(scrollView!)
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! But why exactly is this necessary? Also I though when a argument is optional you should call it like this: `scrollView!.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` and not force unwrap it?

Comment: I meant calling it like this instead: `scrollView?.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)`

Comment: That will not work because the compiler is not sure if the value is not nil. By using `!` you assume it is not nil. If you can't be sure, perform additional check before unwrapping.

Comment: @Nilzone- in this case it's safe to force unwrap (!) since you just assigned a value to scrollView.

Comment: @David but if I wasn't sure, wouldn't it be correct to call it like this:
`scrollView?.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)`? With an `if` check ofcourse