# In swift I cant initialize things before the super.init() or after

Tags: initialization, swift, option-type

I want to be able to initialize the property subviewGroup using self but this gives me the error: Property 'self.gridView' not initialized at super.init call

```
init(frame: NSRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    subviewGroup = GridViewGroup(rows: 9, columns: 9, gridView: self)
}

/***  Properties  ***/
let subviewGroup: GridViewGroup
```

Then if I put the super.init() after the initialization like this

```
init(frame: NSRect) {
    subviewGroup = GridViewGroup(rows: 9, columns: 9, gridView: self)
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

/***  Properties  ***/
let subviewGroup: GridViewGroup
```

I get the error: 'self' used before super.init call

I know I can use an Optional but since it will never be nil after the init() call it seems unnecessary.  Is there a way to do this properly without making subviewGroup an optional?

Here is a working example using an optional

```
/***  Initializers  ***/
init(frame: NSRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    subviewGroup = GridViewGroup(rows: 9, columns: 9, gridView: self)
}

/***  Properties  ***/
let subviewGroup: GridViewGroup?
```

Comment: I know this is similar to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351211/property-not-initialized-at-super-init-call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351211/property-not-initialized-at-super-init-call) but since I don't have enough reputation I couldn't comment on the question

Comment: What I really want to know is if there is a way to not use an Optional

Comment: Do you have a working example using an optional?

Comment: @connor I added an example using an optional

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responses chose @connor because he responded first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly what implicitly unwrapped optionals are good for. You can easily add them to your example like this:

```
/***  Initializers  ***/
init(frame: NSRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    subviewGroup = GridViewGroup(rows: 9, columns: 9, gridView: self)
}

/***  Properties  ***/
let subviewGroup: GridViewGroup!
```

Using an implicitly unwrapped optional allows you to treat the variable as if it weren't an optional and access the underlying directly when you call it.

Using a normal optional your code may look like `var nonoptional: GridViewGroup  = subviewGroup!` while with implicitly unwrapped optionals you can discard the !: `var nonoptional: GridViewGroup = subviewGroup`.

From Apple's docs:

> Implicitly unwrapped optionals are useful when an optional’s value is
>   confirmed to exist immediately after the optional is first defined and
>   can definitely be assumed to exist at every point thereafter. The
>   primary use of implicitly unwrapped optionals in Swift is during class
>   initialization

Answer (score 2):

Your use case is crying out for an implicitly unwrapped optional; this is a perfect example of when you would use one, and this pattern is used in many places throughout the Cocoa Touch API.

To begin with:

A. The proper order of your initialization should be something like this:

```
    init(frame: NSRect) {
        subviewGroup = GridViewGroup(rows: 9, columns: 9, gridView: self)
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
```

...per the Swift Programming Book:

*"A designated initializer must ensure that all of the properties introduced by its class are initialized before it delegates up to a superclass initializer.”*

Then secondly:

B. Declare your `subviewGroup` constant as an implicitly unwrapped optional; doing so gives it a default value of `nil`, meaning that as far as the compiler is concerned the requirement that it be initialized has been met! This form leaves you with a one-time opportunity (since it is a constant, where you used `let`) to assign a non-nil value to it, which you can then do in your initializer without issue as so:

```
let subviewGroup: GridViewGroup!

init(frame: NSRect) {
    subviewGroup = GridViewGroup(rows: 9, columns: 9, gridView: self)
    super.init(frame: frame)
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: note: I suppose that given we have already technically initialized `subviewGroup` by declaring it as an implicitly unwrapped optional, the order of the operations in the init() method as described in *A* above is not as important; however, I believe it would still be good practice to follow the prescribed pattern

Comment: So I am confused by this answer. The compiler complains with: " 'self' used before super.init call "

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution, as you found, is use optional. But because you know it will never be `nil` outside `init`, you can use implicitly unwrapped optional.

```
let subviewGroup: GridViewGroup!
```